# How to avoid duplication in repository and domain layers?

Tags: java, repository, domain-driven-design

Let's imagine that we have a person class, and two different situations:

1) We need get all adults users from database
2) We need split a person group on two - adult and no

So in first case I would prefer do it in repository layer with using where clause.
`Select * from person where age > 18`

And in second case I have a method for determinate is adult person or no.

What is the best practises to avoid duplication of logic in sql and java code in this case ?

Comment: Just an opinion: asking a 'best practice' question to solve a very practical problem doesn't seem right. Look at the implication of each option (such as which runs faster, which consumes the least memory, which is portable, which seems more maintainable, etc.) and decide based on that. Other than that, my personal opinion is for fetching all entries and splitting the list in the application (as long as that makes sense).

Comment: I just tried to demonstrate that I have a two use cases and described what is preferable for me in each of them. A more correct question is if there is some library, a framework or another technology that will give a sufficient abstraction for the method of determining adult age, so that from this abstractions will be possible to generate sql or verify object.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

- add property like `isAdult` into Person entity, it can be caluculated property (`return age>18`), it is the single place your logic resides
- store `isAdult` value in database
- when need get all adults from database you just query `Select * from person where isAdult=1`
- when need distinguish adult person in logic just use property `if (person.isAdult()) ...`